# How to show <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> and ( <?php the_author_posts(); ?> only with post number>0

Tags: php, post

How can i show `<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>` and ( `<?php the_author_posts(); ?>` only with post number>0?

Because if i get the last 2 posts of an author by some category and there aren't posts associated with some author, the problem is that the php code show also the category title with post count==0 when there aren't posts in a category/blog id. How can i hide the category result==0?

I have used this code:

```
    <?php
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // prendi blog corrente

$bids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15); // inserisce l'ID nell'Array
foreach($bids as $bid):
       switch_to_blog($bid); //switch




       ?>  


             <h2 class="elenco"> Ultimi articoli per: <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> ( <?php the_author_posts(); ?>  )  </h2>

       <?php
       $posts = get_posts('author='.$curauth->ID.'&posts_per_page=2');
       foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);?>
```

Comment: Do you have a function that returns the number of posts? Then use `if ($post_count > 0)` around the code that displays the category.

Comment: If i put ($post_count > 0) it still displays also the category name with 0 posts. How can i hidden the post category==0?

Comment: Then you're not putting the `if` around the correct code. Displaying the category name needs to be inside the `if`.

Comment: <h2 class="elenco"> Ultimi articoli per: <?php 
  $posts_count = the_author_posts(); 
  if($posts_count > 0) echo bloginfo('name').' ( '.$posts_count.' )'; 
?>

Comment: You can see the problem here: http://www.studionews24.com/author/mattia-bigongiali/

Comment: I can't see the source code, all I see is the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
<?php
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // prendi blog corrente
$bids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15); // inserisce l'ID nell'Array
foreach($bids as $bid):
   switch_to_blog($bid); //switch
   if($posts = get_posts('author='.$curauth->ID.'&posts_per_page=2')) {
      foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);)
      echo '<h2 class="elenco"> Ultimi articoli per: '.bloginfo('name').'('.the_author_posts().') </h2>';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $posts_count = the_author_posts(); 
  echo $posts_count > 0 : bloginfo('name').' ( '.$posts_count.' )' : ''; 
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
  $posts_count = the_author_posts(); 
  if($posts_count > 0) echo bloginfo('name').' ( '.$posts_count.' )'; 
?>
```

Comment: But the problem is that with the post_count ==0 the posts of a category =0 are still visible. I can see "category:0". I don't wanna to see anything about post category =0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Replace `blogcount()` with whatever function you have to get the number of posts in a category.

```
foreach($bids as $bid):
       switch_to_blog($bid); //switch

       if (postcount() == 0) {
          continue; // Skip to the next blog
       }


       ?>  


             <h2 class="elenco"> Ultimi articoli per: <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> ( <?php the_author_posts(); ?>  )  </h2>

       <?php
       $posts = get_posts('author='.$curauth->ID.'&posts_per_page=2');
       foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);?>
```

Comment: You're a programmer, debug it. I don't know enough about your application to figure it out myself.

Comment: The problem is the condition if. If i hide this condition the php code display. Maybe i have to try another way not with if post_count == 0.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "hide this condition". You need to make sure the `if` is inside the `<?php ... ?>` part of the script.

Comment: Ok, i have debugged.. i have fix an error and then the code is ok. Works 100%, thanks for the advices.